# MySQL query select where MIN Date & Month

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am having trouble figure the query out..

I am try to get the total value from the voucher table.

The month is always keep changing (Prev Month or Next Month) in unix time format.

**PHP**

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', $unixtime);
$month = date('m', $unixtime);
$year = date('Y', $unixtime);
```

**Database 'user_voucher_history':**

```
history_id | user_id |  value | used |  datetime(unixtime)

the smallest date record was 2013-05-05!
```

**Current Query**

```
SELECT 
      IFNULL(SUM(value), 0) AS total 
   FROM user_voucher_history
   WHERE user_id = 2 AND used = 1 AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)) < {$month}
```

the above code: when it comes to 2014 and month 01 it returns 0 so tried different code below and still 0.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUM(value), 0) AS total 
FROM 
  user_voucher_history,
  ( SELECT MIN(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime))) FROM user_voucher_history) AS min_date
WHERE 
  user_id = 2 AND used = 1
  AND (DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)) BETWEEN min_date AND {$date} )
  AND (MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)) < {$month} )
  AND (YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)) < {$year} )
```

please suggestion!!!

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question. I'll try to read it again but in the meanwhile I can tell you that you really want your datetime column as a [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) type.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you want to show the currect rows that matches selected `YEAR` and `MONTH`

Give this a try

```
SELECT 
   IFNULL(SUM(value), 0) AS total 
   FROM user_voucher_history
   WHERE user_id = 2 AND used = 1 AND 
   MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)) < {$month} AND 
   YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)) = {$year}
```

Comment: not match the selected YEAR and MONTH but below or less than that YEAR and MONTH

Comment: Below or less?? DO you mean less or equal? I changed the query

Comment: if month is 12 than below that month 11, 10, 09, et al

Comment: it still returns 0 when it comes to MONTH < 01 AND YEAR < 2014. Because the MIN MONTH was on the 5th (MAY)

Comment: Just to doublecheck, you have a value of datetime in January 2014?

Comment: i want to get the total between the first date of transaction until the selected month and year. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to aggregate over months:

```
SELECT SUM(value)
  FROM user_voucher_history
  WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime) BETWEEN :mindate AND :maxdate
  GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime))
```

BTW you really want to change the type of `datetime` to a date type like [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).